# How can I change the ratio length of line and blank space in dashed CSS border?

Tags: css, border

Does anybody know can I change ratio length of line and blank space in dashed border ( ratio line/blank space to be different ) ?

Comment: Sadly, without using CSS 3's `border-image` (as pointed out by [@dane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028366/dashed-border-problem/4028447#4028447), below) this isn't possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're open to using css3 you can look into the border-image property.

http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/